# Can all equation systems be reduced to the identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I'm trying to learn about solving equation systems using the Gauss-Jordan method. So, you have to convert the equation system to a matrix, and then reduce it to the identity. When you transform it to the augmented matrix, it is pretty easy to find the solutions by going backwards...

- Can *all* equation systems be reduced to the identity matrix? If not, how do you determine whether you can or not?

And, as a side note:

- From my course, it would seem like this is pretty much a "lightbulb" technique. You literally stare at the matrix and suddenly it occurs to you how to proceed. Is that correct? Is there really no standard?

Comment: Not all systems of equations can be reduced to the identity matrix. Only if the matrix is invertible will it be able to be reduced to the identity.

Comment: As an example of a square matrix that can't be, take a system of 4 equations in 4 unknowns, where the second, third, and fourth equations are (respectively) 2, 3, and 4 times the first equation.  Then row reduction leaves the first equation, and 3 rows of 0's, which cannot be reduced to the identity matrix.  E.g. $$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}1 & 2 & 4 & 5\\
2 & 4 & 8 & 10\\
3 & 6 & 12 & 15\\
4 & 8 & 16 & 20\end{array}\right)$$
will row reduce to the matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}1 & 2 & 4 & 5\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: and augmenting (as with solving systems of equations) would not change the row reduction as long as the system is consistent.

Comment: Concerning your side note, this is an important point.  It's not necessarily a light-bulb technique.  Try to get a 1 in the upper left spot by row operations (-1 is fine as well).  Once you have that, you can kill everything beneath it by row operations.  Then try to get a 1 in the second row, first column (or first nonzero column excluding the first column), and repeat, until you have gotten it down to leading 1's in nonzero rows, and 0's beneath all leading 1's.  Sometimes you also want 0's above all leading 1's, but that's not always needed.

Comment: (Reposting an earlier comment, as I realized it sounded condescending without any intention)

Not all equation systems can be reduced to the identity matrix. Take a set of 4 linear equations in 3 unknowns. It is not possible to reduce this to the identity, as the matrix representing the system is not square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all systems of linear equations can be reduced to the identity matrix. A (square) matrix can only be reduced to the identity if the matrix is invertible (i.e., has an inverse). There are many ways to check if a matrix is invertible; some ways include checking if the determinant is non-zero, or if for an $n\times n$ matrix, the rank is $n$.

I wouldn't really say the Gauss-Jordan algorithm is a "lightbulb" technique. It's an algorithm, so you just keep repeating it until the matrix is in (Reduced) Row Echelon Form.

Given for example, \begin{bmatrix}
2&4&2\\
0&2&3\\
3&2&1
\end{bmatrix}
You start with the $a_{11}=2$ and make it $1$ by multiplying the first row by $\frac{1}{2}$.

$\to \begin{bmatrix}
1&2&1\\
0&2&3\\
3&2&1
\end{bmatrix}$

Then you want to make sure $a_{21}=0$. It is already $0$, so we are in luck. So let's move on. We want $a_{31}=1$ next; it's a $3$, so let's multiply row $1$ by $3$ and subtract row $3$.

$\to \begin{bmatrix}
1&2&1\\0&2&3\\0&4&2
\end{bmatrix}$.

Then you want to make $a_{22}=1$ by multiplying row $2$ by $\frac{1}{2}$. And you continue this procedure.

Essentially, you multiply the row by some constant in order to make the term you want into a $1$, and then multiply that $1$ by some constant and add or subtract some row until the numbers below and above it are $0$, just like how we did it for the first column.

Comment: What implications are there for being unable to reduce it to the identity? (like, the system has no solutions?)

Comment: The system can still have solutions, but there might be infinitely many solutions. If we can reduce a matrix to the identity, then we know the matrix has unique solutions.